# Comparator Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

Please find the code below:

```
Collections.sort(longList, new Comparator<Long>() {
                        public int compare(long m1, long m2) {                          
                                return (int) (m2 - m1);                             
                            }
```

For some input it throws the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:763)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:499)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:442)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:239)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:189)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:867)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:229)
```

Please help!

Comment: `public int compare(Long m1, Long m2) {`

Comment: `Comparator` works on Object Data Type `T` , not Primitive Data Type. So, `long` -> `Long`

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have a typo in the question and the actual signature of the compare method is `int compare(Long m1, Long m2)`, or your code wouldn't pass compilation at all, which is not the issue you describe.

The actual issue is that you are trying to compare two longs by returning the difference between them cast to `int`. This may give you incorrect results when the difference is not within the range of the `int` type. You can use `return m2.compareTo(m1)` instead (or `return m2 < m1 ? -1 : m2 > m1 ? 1 : 0` if you don't want to rely on `Long`'s `compareTo` implementation).

Comment: In that case my comparision should be wrong. Why it would throw illegal argument exception

Comment: @BasicCoder This exception can occur when the Comparator gives inconsistent results - for example if compare(a,b) and compare(b,a) are both negative or both positive. The exception will be thrown only when the code that uses the Comparator detects such inconsistency, which is not always the case. I tried your incorrect Comparator on a small list (3 elements) and got wrong order but no exception.

Comment: -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true   Using this helps?

Comment: @BasicCoder Helps in what way?

Comment: Will this ignore the exception? i find this exception as java 7 bug

Comment: @BasicCoder I don't know, but the goal shouldn't be to ignore the exception. It should be to fix the problem that caused the exception in the first place.

Comment: Yes. But this exception cannot be because casting long to int. In that case the sorting order can be different. So trying to find the root cause of this exception

Comment: @BasicCoder Are you still seeing this exception after making one of my suggested changes?

Comment: @BasicCoder Setting the `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` property will prevent the exception from occurring, but the resulting list will possibly end up being sorted incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this:

```
    Comparator<Long> d = new Comparator<Long>() {
        public int compare(long m1, long m2) {
            return (int) (m2 - m1);
        }
    };
```

is the same as **NOT** implementing the abstract method in the comparator interface

```
public int compare(T a1, T a2);
```

so your code is not compiling

you should use (is java8) the method reference

```
Comparator<Long> d = Long::compare;
```

but what is wrong whit this: `(int) (m2 - m1);` may you be asking yourself...

well you are forcing a cast of 2 a long into a integer, so that result can be a very negative  Long or a positive integer

check this example to clarify:

```
    long b = 1000_000_000_000_000L;
    long a = 100L;
    System.out.println(a - b);
    System.out.println((int) (a - b));
```

the result is 
as long

> -999999999999900

as int

> 1530495076

which is definitely breaking the comparation results

Comment: In that case my comparision should be wrong. Why it would throw illegal argument exception

Comment: The signature of `Long::compare` is `int compare(long, long)`, not `int compare(Long, Long)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(3L, 2L, 1L);

    list.sort(new Comparator<Long>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Long o1, Long o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });

    System.out.println(list);
```

OR:

```
    List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(3L, 2L, 1L);
    list.sort(Long::compareTo);
    System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things worth mentioning here:

- you **always** use @Override when you write down a method of which you think should *override* something. Then the compiler can tell you when you got something wrong (as in your case, where the signature expects Long, but you used long)
- Avoid re-inventing the wheel, even when it is just for reversing the comparison.

In other words: instead of doing

```
int compare(Long l1, long l2) {
  return l2 - l1;
```

you could do:

```
  return l2.compareTo(l1);
```

instead. That is just easier to read; and performance is basically the same.